# How to infer index type based on user input?

Tags: typescript

I'm receiving dynamic user input, in the form of user uploaded columns with user generated data. Depending on whether a column is of type `string` or `number` I am creating slightly different objects to represent each column. I'm then using those column objects to access data in each row.

I'm trying to make it so when I access row data, I'm able to infer the correct cell type (`StringCell` or `NumberCell`), given the column type that I'm accessing it with. Note that I do not know any of the keys in advance that I'll be using, as the data is all user input.

How can I achieve it so the type `StringCell` is inferred in the example below?

[SNIPPET HERE](https://playcode.io/988744)

```
enum ColumnTypes {
    STRING_COLUMN = "STRING_COLUMN",
    NUMBER_COLUMN = "NUMBER_COLUMN",
}

interface StringCell {
    value: string
}

interface NumberCell {
    value: number
    displayValue: string
}

interface rowDataType {
    [key: string]: NumberCell | StringCell
    // Row data will have many other properties but we don't know
    // What they will be in advanced because it's all user defined
    colNameX: StringCell
    colName2: NumberCell
}
```

```
// NOTE THAT THIS DATA IS DYNAMICALLY GENERATED
// We haven't defined this so we don't know types in advance
const stringCellData: StringCell = {
  value: 'abc'
}

const numberCellData: NumberCell = {
    value: 123,
    displayValue: '$123',
}

const rowOfData: rowDataType = {
    colNameX: stringCellData, 
    colName2: numberCellData,
}

const columns = [
    {
      key: 'colNameX',
      type: ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN,
    },
    {
      key: 'colName2',
      type: ColumnTypes.NUMBER_COLUMN,
    }
]

let res
columns.forEach(col => {
    switch (col.type) {
        case ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN:
            res = rowOfData[col.key] 
            console.log(res) // RES TYPE SHOULD BE A `StringCell`
        case ColumnTypes.NUMBER_COLUMN:
            res = rowOfData[col.key] 
            console.log(res) // RES TYPE SHOULD BE A `NumberCell`
    }
})
```

Comment: The code you provided here is really confusing to me. The lower snipped seems to be vaguely related to the top one, as you are not using any of those types in the lower snipped at all. Is `myMainObject` supposed to be of type `MyMainType`? If so, why does it have two properties which are not defined at all in the `interface`? It is not clear to me at all what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the `if` statement, when you are returning the same object in both branches?

Comment: WHat are you trying to achieve here `keyof MyMainType & KeyTypes.NUMBER_KEY` ? If you want to extend, you need to use union `|`

Comment: @TobiasS. They aren't assigning the same object; one has `abc` and the other has `def` keys.

Comment: I take your points, that makes sense. I've rewritten the entire question to make it less abstract and fix the flaws you pointed out.

Comment: `key` is not defined in your second snippet. Could you just make a minimal reproducible example in a playground and send us the link?

Comment: I don't see any static relationship between `key` and `type` so I would be surprised the type system can help you much here - what you can do is write type guard functions with which you observe the actual structures given to you. In that case you don't even need the column type.

Comment: I added a snippet to my post @caTS

Comment: @flq The static relationship isn't between `key` and `type` BUT we know that if we index `key` within a `Column` that is `STRING_COLUMN` we should get a `StringCell` back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `column` and `rowOfData` come from user input, we cannot use their type statically to associate the column keys with cell data types. We will have to **assert** these types at some point.

Then we want to be able to have the cell data (`res`) type to be automatically inferred from the `switch case` value.

As stated first, we could assert it everytime:

```
switch (col.type) {
  case ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN:
    res = rowOfData[col.key] as StringCell // rowOfData is arbitrary
```

But somehow we would like something more automatic.

The difficulty is that the type hint is at one place (`col.type`), and the associated data to be asserted is somewhere else (`rowOfData[col.key]`).

The typical (and somehow still complex) solution is to gather all the information in a single data structure, so that the correlation between the type hint and the data is together, and to generate all possible types as *union*, so that we are left with performing a [union discrimination](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), which TypeScript handles fine:

```
// Type conversion helper
type ColumnTypeToCellType = {
    [ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN]: StringCell
    [ColumnTypes.NUMBER_COLUMN]: NumberCell
}

// Associate a column type hint with the cell data, so they can be correlated
interface ColumnWithCellData<CT extends ColumnTypes> {
    key: string
    type: CT
    cellData: ColumnTypeToCellType[CT]
}

// Generate a union of all possible correlated types
type ColumnWithCellDataUnion = { [CT in ColumnTypes]: ColumnWithCellData<CT> }[ColumnTypes]
//   ^? ColumnWithCellData<ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN> | ColumnWithCellData<ColumnTypes.NUMBER_COLUMN>

/**
 * Extract the cell data from the row for the given column,
 * generate a correlated object of column type and the cell data
 */
function getColData(column: { key: string, type: ColumnTypes }, rowOfData: rowDataType) {
    return {
        ...column,
        cellData: rowOfData[column.key]
    } as ColumnWithCellDataUnion // column and rowOfData are arbitrary (come from user input), so they must be asserted at some point
}

columns.forEach(col => {
    const colAndCellData = getColData(col, rowOfData) // Extract in a single place, it is asserted as a union
    // This now becomes a union discrimination
    switch (colAndCellData.type) {
        case ColumnTypes.STRING_COLUMN:
            colAndCellData.cellData.value // string
            //             ^? StringCell
            break; // Make sure to break, otherwise the fallthrough makes `colAndCellData` become multiple possible types again
        case ColumnTypes.NUMBER_COLUMN:
            colAndCellData.cellData.displayValue // Okay, string
            //             ^? NumberCell
            break;
    }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gG0iAKgTwA7AM5QN4BQUxUAyigEoCSAcgOID6MA8gDICqAsjVALxQAictXpM2XGgIA0REjS4AhAKIUxHbn0HzOy1S3WSZAXwIEAliAAuwAE4AzAIYBjYGUs2LAcxjAECfLLEAG4OSMAAXFDY7l4EJuZWto4uUDSQAEa2Pn4BJFAhYZHgEJk2gVAAJmbYGAgOaABqoWARUTEgnnGmFtb2zq42cADuACIOlg7oWLkkANoA1sBokdEeHQC6kWklWb7+AD5ua9575QD0Z1AUw5XjDlBDZjkAFg5BrhAOIGhQcJbPtigGEGWBsljMOCg6TAlgergqcBAAHJYfMQMNzpcAOqvWH-JYPJ7+TJQCxQBwVEIgFwVKHAJwOMDYVxmSxI3ChfxMwEVYB2CzACrlJyIGgOCDAAAakVI7ROfmFovFwAATFsMrsFSYLqlmCglFAUAAJACCKENRqopCgIzNJqgVptAE0aCbOFQYCbWKwnVA6EoaCozUoRgQdVjXK93sjYbz+SBBVB-tUonA4ZVESioGibpZMJCyRSqS4CCKQNE2sdsggxhMZXLq5pCHkCi1IkiHOknEiuqXERXiqVq7WHOqdjZG-xmyRW60AIwqgDMMjyVRqdUazVaSIAJAvF0jjKYyxXBkNmHYR5EzyOpq4p4qEGKJdLK15h3cVyQRU-lWqoIOmo1p+vYnrCP7ILg-CzOU055MQizLFASI-s+UqHuUeR5lgkTwEgECoPm2AAHTCLQjD6BIX7EEY1EzPB2ZLO2qF-hhDHENhrR4cgd4kdouhqFR5QmOspg6neUBlu8NjYGYiJQACCCggQnGwIgPH5igcDVhJD55LM3EEbxpGUORgncJsRzvqc+mGYRWB8YoKjmTQlnbEOpzxDqJrYNgcBOGY4yuPcEEEUm+YKT0hL-EmAKSXstwTFIqaxQSDIgHSklwDYNi+EFQo9Ek-RqfhIBYqyzwfhMAA8MDmsAAAe1ggBUuB2bxAB89GMUhqyxFh+a4Sgwp7FeJUaVgWk6fmBkoKJXmXHQoC2EF5JQGAIByRlcB2OSOQYHAvlmOkCCuCKOV5dYtKcdgKkRXZ5X-FVDjsJt8lTlAs2khl7VEZZD0Vc9tUoF1RgGepRl-WGlzEAAegA-GJABUSNEEjUBKE1NjOHicUuDkFR3FAdiDNA+JQGexPZalUCeGY0ZZaVK7o54y3Y9Ya3nbldRXb86QAFb0rCO2M8g4XTF8114wlhMTGjZwEHYG1OOC8ms5YeEjgAFKFICRHgPUrHKyWcbhEP2ZCtEU8MF5jTedx3gAlN1uWWGANgZXB8HET7ut0Xk+PAXW1vnpedyzLrxGIaJeRGOSbXm49lWjXcr1bVAOq6+SLUh7bRMOLl5I2OkrLYzYPw63AErE6T63MjY30YDCjvJX5qU-BATKwiSDi+bYvPjKm1cHT0oHmyRdjZUozjPJX-i8F1XtgYzJotc9mjq5rdxz8lZ55xMzs6pj7g499a2yR0p1AnULjJaypIcn3YKJr3a0bVtmKGs8KbokMdIihKDk603oZTXE4DwEALDjA-nkHUzxLCWAwNgcIFwhhoOIjdcBZgMCWDqB0Yi2VPBnARE4bAZxXgtXSHAOA8wzgqjOCAAuZ4vDEXgRABAABiMBECoFXQALTv37OUbAjxLBOGeFAOeq8KjPQwfmZ2XsA691cL9ByJkRAUXENwcImF2I-mkbIwOI5iKzgzpcPqHRdEMR1OxeCCMrHwXSLlBw8wADcZioCcBca4bA7tXCWDTE44ALjkp-ABDYR4zIaaOD8P8QYYBPASM+IsXAAADfRa8U4TFSf-KuHwwAIHBLUVwB0jonX8URckngHAWAcQyKJqicDEX4s5Si2iHEB0QAYrJDhiJGLuMRNctR6hNDCB45g8x6itzlB0kgNjbEkHsQskgQSXGuOEnER2QA)